# Trouble migrating from mongoose.connect() to mongoose.createConnection()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When using mongoose.createConnection, how do I access the model from my router? Do I have to mongoose.createConnection every time? Im using this pattern from the docs:

```
//app.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
conn.model('User', require('../schemas/user'));
conn.model('PageView', require('./schemas/pageView'));

module.exports = conn;
```

**Now, this does not work:**

```
//router.js

const PageView = require('./schemas/pageView');
```

..I understand that it does not work because I am no longer exporting the model from the schema file, just the schema:

```
// ./schemas/pageView.js

module.exports = PageViewSchema;
```

Prior to using createConnection, I've used the default **mongoose.connect()** in my app.js, so I'd simply export the model, like this:

```
// ./schemas/pageView.js

const PageView = mongoose.model("PageView", PageViewSchema);
module.exports = PageView;
```

**How can I avoid needing to createConnection in every file I want to use the model?**

Comment: So setting  `global.conn = mongoose.createConnection()`  in app.js, does allow me to use `const PageView = conn.model("pageView");` in my router...I am not sure that scoping the connection globally is the best solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From mongoose NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)

> Important! If you opened a separate connection using
> mongoose.createConnection() but attempt to access the model through
> mongoose.model('ModelName') it will not work as expected since it is
> not hooked up to an active db connection. In this case access your
> model through the connection you created:
>
> ```
> const conn = mongoose.createConnection('your connection string'); 
> const MyModel = conn.model('ModelName', schema);
> const m = new MyModel;
> m.save(); 
> // works
> ```
>
> vs
>
> ```
> const conn = mongoose.createConnection('your connection string');
> const MyModel = mongoose.model('ModelName', schema); 
> const m = new MyModel; 
> m.save();
> // does not work b/c the default connection object was never connected
> ```